# Is it proper for RESTful Service GET to only return an object for the user to process for an actual answer?

Tags: rest, http, get

In this first scenario, the URI for the GET method could be the following :

```
http://myserver/number/getItem?itemID
```

The user passes in an Item ID # and the RESTful Services GETs that Item and returns the item object back to the user so the user can extract whatever info is desired.

**This is the Scenario in question**

In this scenario, the URI for the GET method could be the following :

```
http://myserver/number/overLimit?itemID
```

The user passes in an Item ID # and the RESTful Services GETs that Item so it can be determined if overweight.

There are 3 options at this point.

1 - Return the Item object as described above and just have the user retrieve the info.

OR

2 - Return just the weight and let the user determine if its overweight.

OR

3 - Return a boolean value with the answer true if overweight and false if not.

When using proper RESTful Services, does it matter which of the 3 is used? Are any rules broken by implementing either of the 3 scenarios?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When using proper RESTful Services, does it matter which of the 3 is used? Are any rules broken by implementing either of the 3 scenarios?

No, it does not matter which of those three patterns is used.  No rules are broken.

[Uniform Resource Identifiers](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-1.1) identify resources.

[Resources](https://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Efielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm#sec_5_2_1_1): Any information that can be named can be a resource: a document or image, a temporal service (e.g. "today's weather in Los Angeles"), a collection of other resources, a non-virtual object (e.g. a person), and so on. In other words, any concept that might be the target of an author's hypertext reference must fit within the definition of a resource.

REST doesn't care whether you use a single large grained resource that provides you with a representation of every piece of information that you might ever need, or multiple fine grained resources with representations optimized for particular use cases.

[Large grained resources](https://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/dataTransferObject.html) are great when you are concerned about how expensive it is to send information across a network, but you give up fine grained cache control.